# Expanding brackets of matrices with the identity

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

So I'm expanding $(I_n-A)(A^0+A^1+...+A^k)$

I sort of know that because it is the identity here, that this expansion is equal to $I_nA^0+I_nA^1+...+I_nA^k-A^1-A^2-...-A^{k+1}$, but I want to know if there's a rigorous argument as to why this is true? I know it is something to do with the fact that we have the identity here, as it isn't true for any two matrices $A$ and $B$.

I tried by considering each element of $I_n-A$ but that just got too confusing, so is there any rigorous explanation as to why it holds?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Matrix multiplication in general is distributive. If $A$ is $m\times n$ matrix and $B,C$ are $n\times p$ matrices then for all $1\leq i\leq m,1\leq j\leq p$ we have:

$(A(B+C))_{ij}=\sum_{k=1}^n A_{ik}(B+C)_{kj}=\sum_{k=1}^n A_{ik}B_{kj}+\sum_{k=1}^n A_{ik}C_{kj}=(AB)_{ij}+(AC)_{ij}$

So $A(B+C)=AB+AC$. From here you can easily prove what you wanted to prove. So I don't think it has something to do with identity, assuming I understood your question right.

Comment: Oh right, lovely thanks! Sorry I think that maybe I just got confused and forgot that rule! but thank you so much

Comment: @Lauren please accept the answer so others can see that this question has been answered and to give Mark credit